# Removing observer of NSNotificationCenter in Singleton Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsnotificationcenter

Quick question:

I have a singleton class which is a registered for several NSNotifications. Since Singletons last over the app's lifetime.

Do I have to implement

```
  [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

In my singleton class?

Whats the right way to deal with NSNotification center in Singletons in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [If add an observer for a notification in the AppDelegate, do I need to bother removing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560419/if-add-an-observer-for-a-notification-in-the-appdelegate-do-i-need-to-bother-re)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't need to stop observing in this case.  The only time that the memory used by a true Singleton will ever be deallocated is when the program exits.  When the program exits, it goes ahead and deallocates **all** of the memory and resources that are being used anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just for `Memory` sake, you should properly remove it in the `-dealloc`.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, in a singleton the memory will be removed when the program exits anyway....  The whole point of a singleton is to remain in memory as long as the program is running.

Comment: this would serve developer's memory if at some time class will be changed for non-singleton use

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your singleton listen to notification throughout your app then there is no need of removing it.

If you want that at certain point your singleton should stop receiving notifications then you can add a method in your singleton and can call it where needed

```
- (void)removeObserver {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self] ;
}
```